# Data visualisation widget for list comparison

Tags: java, swt

I am looking for a widget that allow lists comparison, like it is done for genome comparison:
We display two lists horizontally for example, and we draw some lines between identical elements between the 2 lists, in order to show which elements are identical in those two lists, and where they are.

It is better if it works with SWT, but I am open to every proposition, it could also be a web based widget.

I already looked for such a widget, but I don't find anything satisfactory.
Thank you for your help, and I hope that my request is relevant.
If it is not, where could I ask this question?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at the D3 javascript library?

Comment: Yes why not. I don't know this library, but from what I see,  I don't like the way it is done, with the code, It look old fashion style.

Comment: Can't comment to that, I havent had the need to use it in years, I just remember it being easy enough for a no JS dev to pick up and did what I needed with minimum fuss.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help, It could do the job indeed!